# react .map with selected attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I need to display an element using map with a specific attribute.

My code displays attributes from all item objects.

```
const {report, info} = this.state;
const max = this.state.info.map((info, index) =>
    <DonateReport key={index} title={info.title} opened={info.opened}
                  onClick={() => this.toggleInfo(index)}>
        {report.map(({item}) => ( //<--HERE
                <h2 >{item.donaters_count}</h2>
    ))}
    </DonateReport>
);
```

Tell me, please, how to display an attribute with the following parameter: `item.month == info.key` 
Perhaps there are still ways to solve this problem...

I would really appreciate any help. Do not swear, please, I am really sitting over this problem the second day

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want exactly without knowing more about your data structure. Maybe create a minimal example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/). That would help us helping you debugging your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would help more if you show what you are trying to do.
I understood that you're trying to filter showing an attribute based on the month. I could be wrong though

```
const {report, info} = this.state;
const max = this.state.info.map((info, index) =>
    <DonateReport key={index} title={info.title} opened={info.opened}
                  onClick={() => this.toggleInfo(index)}>
        {report.filter((item) => item.month == info.key).map(({item}) => ( 
                <h2 >{item.donaters_count}</h2>
        ))}
    </DonateReport>
);
```

Comment: it seems to me using filter and map is redundant. if we use just map, and in that we perform our conditional check. if it is passed, we can return the appropriate jsx or else null. I have also provided the answer. Can you check it once. thanks.

Comment: @Manya for that you might want to use reduce. Then you don't have null values in your array.

Comment: @JanPeter. You are right. But here in the question, he is not making an array. the array which is generated by map function, is directly being rendered by react. so react will not render the items with value null. If I use reduce here, I will need to have some kind of aggregator. what is your preference considering this ?

Comment: That's right, it really depends on what he is really trying todo. But to be honest, I still don't quite get what the actual question is. I already had a view at the Codesandbox example, but that didn't help.

Comment: I think this way should work! now it shows an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'donaters_count' of undefined. Do I understand correctly, after the filter only the item.month attribute remains? Is it possible to return the whole object with the necessary attribute?

Comment: try removing big brackets``{}`` and just use item in the arrow functions

Comment: yes, that helped. thank you all guys for help, you saved my day!! <3

Comment: @chapaev_in_hole according to me this is not the most optimized solution. better you reduce or map, instead of filter and then map

Comment: @kumarmo2 I agree with you. Reduce could be a better optimization for this.

Comment: @MohammadAlbakri. One thing that I am not getting is why will react print the ``null`. ?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `ternary operator` and formatted your DonateReport Component a bit. It should work for you. Let me know.

```
 <DonateReport key={index} title={info.title} opened={info.opened}
                        onClick={() => this.toggleInfo(index)}>
                        {
                            report.map(item => this.state.info.key === item.month ? //<--HERE
                            <h2 >{item.donaters_count}</h2>
                            : null)
                        }
                    </DonateReport>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it checks the first object that arrives, and immediately displays a null. but the code is working :)

Comment: @chapaev_in_hole. just one more thing. if you find the answer useful, please either upvote or make it as correct. thanks